# Multiple Inheritance of Joined Table Inheritance in Sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, multiple-inheritance

I' like to define a model which inheritance from two base models in flask-sqlalchemy as follows:

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(). primary_key=1)

class BaseModelA(BaseModel):
    base_model_a_field = db.Column(db.String(9))
    base_model_a_type = db.Column(db.String(9))
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "a", "polymorphic_on": base_model_a_type}

class BaseModelB(BaseModel):
    base_model_b_field = db.Column(db.String(9))
    base_model_b_type = db.Column(db.String(9))
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "b", "polymorphic_on": base_model_b_type}

class InheritancedModel(BaseModelA, BaseModelB):

    model_a_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("base_model_a.id"), primary_key=1)
    model_b_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("base_model_b.id"), primary_key=1)

    other_field = db.Column(db.String(9))
```

When create the instance of `InheritancedModel`,

`IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` happens.

Can i do multiple inheritance of joined table inheritance in sqlalchemy?

I can't find any info about multiple inheritance in sqlalchemy.

Comment: Multiple inheritance works, but you can't combine two separate polymorphic hierarchies like this.

Comment: @univerio Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Well, why do you want to combine two separate polymorphic hierarchies?

Comment: What does `combine two separate polymorphic hierarchies` mean?

Comment: What I mean by that is, a subtree in the inheritance graph where all classes have the same `polymorphic_on`. Instead of using abstract terms like `BaseModelA`, perhaps you can give me a concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have two base models. One is `Attendance(BaseModelA)`, it has two subclasses: `Clock`, `Leave`. The other base model is `AuditItem(BaseModelB)`, it has three subclasses: `Leave`, `Expense`, `Loan`. The `Leave` model inheritance from `Attendance` and `AuditItem`

Comment: You basically want a composition scenario, not a strictly inheritance one. What you should do is set up single-table polymorphism on `BaseModel` with type `clock`, `leave`, `expense`, and `loan`, and then mix in traits like `Attendance` and `AuditItem` as necessary. See [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/inheritance.html#resolving-column-conflicts).